# Highcharts extracting x and y coordinates from event.target

Tags: highcharts

I just started using highcharts and I am having a difficult time getting the X and Y coordinates from an event object. I have an event listiner associated with a flags' series but I can't seem to extract x and y. This is my code:

```
function App() {
(...)

const options = {
    title: {
        (...)
        },
        align: "left",
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    subtitle: {
        (...)
    },
    chart: {
        (...)
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        gridLineDashStyle: "dot",
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: "#ffffff",
            },
        },
    },
    yAxis: [
        {
            labels: {
                align: "right",
                style: {
                    color: "#ffffff",
                },
            },
            height: "70%",
            lineWidth: 2,
            resize: {
                enabled: true,
            },
            gridLineDashStyle: "dot",
        },
        {
            labels: {
                align: "right",
                style: {
                    color: "#ffffff",
                },
            },
            top: "75%",
            height: "25%",
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2,
            gridLineDashStyle: "dot",
        },
    ],
    legend: {
        (...)
    },
    plotOptions: {
        (...)
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: "area",
            (...)
        },
        {
            type: "flags",
            data: flagEvents,
            onSeries: "solarWindStock",
            shape: "circlepin",
            width: 16,
            showInLegend: false,
            events: {
                mouseOver: function (event) {
                    console.log(event.target);
                },
            },
        },
        {
            (...)
        },
        {
            (...)
        },
    ],
};

return (
    <div>
        <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts}
            constructorType={"stockChart"}
            options={options}
        />
        <EventsTable events={events} />
    </div>
);
```

}

I would like to use the X coordinate from the flag that I am hovering.

https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-challenge-gu7s8?file=/src/App.js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a runnable snippet on jsfiddle like website so that I can test.

Comment: Hi @StefanWang. You can find it here https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-challenge-gu7s8?file=/src/App.js  It is currently logging the event.target object when a flag is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this config to point out the flag properties:

```
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            color: "#ffffff",
        },
        flags: {
            width: 16,
            showInLegend: false,
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        console.log(this)
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
```

Notice that there is no arrow function, because `() =>` changes the scope.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-challenge-forked-pvpzt

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.flags.point.events.mouseOver